# How to use Double? nullable type with Math.Round in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do something like this but C# doesn't accept this:

```
    public static void setPrice(Double? value)
    {

        if (value != null) {
            this.TextBoxPrice.Text = Math.Round(value, 2).ToString();
        } else {
            this.TextBoxPrice.Text = "No Price";   
        }

    }
```

So does it mean using nullable type Double? is completely useless in this use case ? What can I use then ?

Update: I made a mystypo I actually meant

```
    public static void setPrice(Double? value)
```

so I corrected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're not currently using a nullable type - `Double` is a non-nullable value type, so can never be null. This is what you want:

```
public static void setPrice(Double? value)
{

    if (value != null) {
        this.TextBoxPrice.Text = Math.Round(value.Value, 2).ToString();
    } else {
        this.TextBoxPrice.Text = "No Price";   
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you should *not* be using a `double` to represent financial values. It's inappropriate as a *binary* floating point type. Use `decimal` (or `decimal?`) instead.

(Note that `Double?` is equivalent to `Nullable<Double>`.)

If you've come from a Java background, you may be expecting `Double` to be a reference "wrapper" type to start with - it's not. In C# `double` is simply an alias for `System.Double`; they're the same type.

Comment: I made a mystypo I actually use Double? so my code is like yours and it doesn't work.

Comment: @user you missed that Jon inserted a `.Value` when passing the `double?` to `Math.Round`. And that fixes your code, because it converts `double?` to `double`. And `Math.Round` expects `double` but not `double?`.

Answer (score 13):

Jon's answer is fine -- pay particular attention to the bit about decimal -- but I thought I'd add that you can "lift" methods to nullable using higher-order programming. For example:

```
public static Func<T?, T?> Lift<T>(Func<T, T> func) where T : struct
{
    return (T? t)=>t.HasValue ? (T?)func(t.Value) : (T?)null;
}

public static Func<A?, R> LiftRef<A, R>(Func<A, R> func) where A : struct where R : class
{
    return (A? a)=>a.HasValue ? func(a.Value) : null;
}
```

And now you can say:

```
Func<decimal, decimal> round2 = x=>Math.Round(x, 2);
Func<decimal?, decimal?> liftedRound2 = Lift(round2);
Func<decimal?, string> liftedToString = LiftRef(decimal.ToString);
...

public static void SetPrice(decimal? value)
{
    this.TextBoxPrice.Text == liftedToString(liftedRound2(value)) ?? "No Price";
}
```

Comment: I may use this as an example of the most question marks in the shortest amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon Skeet's answer and just wanted to add that in that specific case you might consider simply adding a ClearPrice method - for reasons of clearer API + avoiding the if-else.